Unable to acquire session bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
I installed Ubuntu 24.10 on the WSL.
When executing self-programmed programs with Gtk4, I receive the following error message:
Gtk-WARNING **: 14:01:59.470: Unable to acquire session bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory

The program itself works normally.
Does anyone have an idea?
